# Xcode 7.3 process launch failed: unknown failure

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm struggling trying to launch a project but I can't.
The project runs perfectly on simulator but when I try it on iphone 6 (IOS 9.3) fails, the project is installed on the desired device but is not launched.
I've deleted the derived data but I don't know what can I do to solve the issue

[image]

I don't understand the output of the window/device/log I describe below:

```js
Aug 27 14:29:26 Eduardos-iPhone installd[50] <Notice>: 0x16e12f000 -[MIClientConnection _doBackgroundInstallationForPath:withOptions:completion:]: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/vipp.app.ios.app_sparse.ipa" type Developer (LSInstallType = (null)) requested by streaming_zip_conduit (pid 276)
Aug 27 14:29:26 Eduardos-iPhone installd[50] <Notice>: 0x16e12f000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing <MIInstallableBundlePatch ID=com.Bitam.vipp-app-ios; Version=1.0, ShortVersion=1.0>
Aug 27 14:29:26 Eduardos-iPhone installd[50] <Notice>: 0x16e12f000 -[MIInstallableBundlePatch applyPatchWithError:]: Attempting patch update of com.Bitam.vipp-app-ios from 1.0 (1.0) to 1.0 (1.0)
Aug 27 14:29:26 Eduardos-iPhone profiled[154] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Provisioning profiles changed
Aug 27 14:29:26 Eduardos-iPhone profiled[154] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Updating MIS trust...
Aug 27 14:29:26 Eduardos-iPhone securityd[98] <Error>:  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
Aug 27 14:29:26 Eduardos-iPhone securityd[98] <Error>:  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
Aug 27 14:29:26 Eduardos-iPhone installd[50] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Aug 27 14:29:27 Eduardos-iPhone securityd[98] <Error>:  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
Aug 27 14:29:27 Eduardos-iPhone securityd[98] <Error>:  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
Aug 27 14:29:27 Eduardos-iPhone installd[50] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Aug 27 14:29:27 Eduardos-iPhone securityd[98] <Error>:  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
Aug 27 14:29:27 Eduardos-iPhone securityd[98] <Error>:  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
Aug 27 14:29:27 Eduardos-iPhone installd[50] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Aug 27 14:29:27 Eduardos-iPhone securityd[98] <Error>:  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
Aug 27 14:29:27 Eduardos-iPhone securityd[98] <Error>:  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
Aug 27 14:29:27 Eduardos-iPhone installd[50] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Aug 27 14:29:27 Eduardos-iPhone securityd[98] <Error>:  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
Aug 27 14:29:27 Eduardos-iPhone securityd[98] <Error>:  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
Aug 27 14:29:27 Eduardos-iPhone installd[50] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Aug 27 14:29:27 Eduardos-iPhone installd[50] <Notice>: 0x16e12f000 -[MIInstallableBundle _refreshUUIDForContainer:withError:]: Data container for com.Bitam.vipp-app-ios is now at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A5BC5AD3-16B6-4C6B-900C-0AC6CFB62F86
Aug 27 14:29:27 Eduardos-iPhone installd[50] <Notice>: 0x16e12f000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:reason:withError:]: Made container live for com.Bitam.vipp-app-ios at /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/48FD12A3-A17B-4DE5-9A57-CF8F6A5E7036
Aug 27 14:29:27 Eduardos-iPhone installd[50] <Notice>: 0x16e12f000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Install Successful; Staging: 0.00s; Waiting: 0.00s; Preflight/Patch: 0.31s, Verifying: 0.11s; Overall: 0.66s
Aug 27 14:29:27 Eduardos-iPhone pkd[160] <Warning>: releasing plug-in hold B5E9BC0E-BB8B-41BA-9F25-E44036C5B7D7 at client's request
Aug 27 14:29:27 Eduardos-iPhone online-auth-agent[214] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Aug 27 14:29:27 Eduardos-iPhone SpringBoard[58] <Warning>: Installed apps did change.
    Added: {(
    )}
    Removed: {(
    )}
    Modified: {(
        "com.Bitam.vipp-app-ios"
    )}
Aug 27 14:29:29 Eduardos-iPhone com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver  PROJECT:debugserver-340.3.124
    [298] <Warning>: debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver  PROJECT:debugserver-340.3.124
     for arm64.
Aug 27 14:29:29 Eduardos-iPhone com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver  PROJECT:debugserver-340.3.124
    [298] <Warning>: Connecting to com.apple.debugserver service...
Aug 27 14:29:29 Eduardos-iPhone com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver  PROJECT:debugserver-340.3.124
    [298] <Warning>: Got a connection, waiting for process information for launching or attaching.
Aug 27 14:29:29 Eduardos-iPhone com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver  PROJECT:debugserver-340.3.124
    [298] <Warning>: 1 +0.000000 sec [012a/0c07]: RNBRunLoopLaunchInferior DNBProcessLaunch() failed to launch process, unknown failure
Aug 27 14:29:29 Eduardos-iPhone com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver  PROJECT:debugserver-340.3.124
    [298] <Warning>: error: failed to launch process /Developer/usr/bin/debugserver: <unknown failure>
Aug 27 14:29:29 Eduardos-iPhone com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver  PROJECT:debugserver-340.3.124
    [298] <Warning>: 2 +0.000560 sec [012a/1107]: error: ::read ( -1, 0x16e246a38, 1024 ) => -1 err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009)
Aug 27 14:29:29 Eduardos-iPhone com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver  PROJECT:debugserver-340.3.124
    [298] <Warning>: Exiting.
Aug 27 14:29:39 Eduardos-iPhone assistant_service[195] <Warning>: Error getting NanoAppRegistry workspace info: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.nanoappregistry.workspace was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.nanoappregistry.workspace was invalidated.}
Aug 27 14:29:39 Eduardos-iPhone assistant_service[195] <Warning>: Error getting NanoAppRegistry workspace info: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.nanoappregistry.workspace was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.nanoappregistry.workspace was invalidated.}
Aug 27 14:29:39 Eduardos-iPhone calaccessd[165] <Warning>: ERROR: couldn't find any operation group that responds to the selector CADDatabaseGetSharedCalendarInvitationsWithReply:
Aug 27 14:29:39 Eduardos-iPhone calaccessd[165] <Warning>: ERROR: couldn't find any operation group that responds to the invocation CADDatabaseGetSharedCalendarInvitationsWithReply:
Aug 27 14:29:39 Eduardos-iPhone assistant_service[195] <Warning>: Error getting shared calendar invitations for entity types 2 from daemon: Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1014 "(null)"
```

Comment: If you open Xcode's devices window, select your device, and examine the console log at the bottom, does it have any information about errors during the installation and launch attempt?

Comment: @PhillipMills I've edited the question sharing the output.

Comment: sorry but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure you have set proper values to  *Code Signing Identity* and *Provisioning Profile* of your target under build settings.**

Try keeping *Provisioning Profile* as *Automatic* and *Code Signing Identity* as iOS Developer.

[image]

**If Ad-Hoc Provisioning profile is set then such errors are prone to occur.**

Comment: the configuration in xcode is the same as yours, but the issue persists

Answer (score 0):

Make developer profile for your device UID on developer.apple.com and choose it in provisioning profile field in Build Settings. Sometimes this error appears and this is the only way to avoid it